# How to Convert Visual Basic Str() to Java code

Tags: java, vb6, code-conversion

I was wondering if there is a better implementation for converting the following VB6 snippets in Immediate window to Java:

```
? Format("002-", "")
-2
? Str("002-")
-2
```

My Java code scans through the string and if it sees a negative sign, converts the string to a negative integer, else positive.  I would like to know if Java has a utility function which functions the same way as this.

A link to the Str function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6a1sx7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
VB6       Java
---       -----
Str()     Integer.toString ();  # Convert integer to string
***       Integer.ParseInt ();  # Convert string to integer
Format()  String.Format ();
```

Here are some links:

- Integer.ParseInt():  http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/simple.html
- String.Format(): http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1195/

Comment: Integer.parseInt("002-"); does not parse similar to Str().  I think it throws a NumberFormatException.

Comment: @nmenego - you're correct.  Before you edited your post with the VB.Net link, I incorrectly recalled VB6 "Str()" as string-to-integer.  I filled out the table with both variants: string to integer (parseInt()), and integer to string (toString()).

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think it'll work. I am give a string "23-" and it is supposed to be converted to -23 int.

Comment: Q: Why are you giving a string of "23-" (instead of "-23")?  And you're saying VB used to accept it?  That suprises me ;).  Q: Do you know if VB.Net also accepts it?  Q: What was the reason?  Q: Can you just pass in a string with the sign in the usual place?

Comment: Suggestion: just use a Java [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to convert the string (before you try to parse it):

Comment: Yes, VB can parse both 23- and -23. I have no idea if VB.net does the same. The system I am converting Java from VB receives that string '23-' and the VB code parses it to be -23.